# Link to objects that have links to other objects

Tags: objects, workflow, linked-data, groups

I'm complete newbie in blender.

For example I have A, B, C models. Every model is saved in a separate *.blend file. A and B are linked into C as proxies and somehow transformed to form C. Then I want to use this C object as a part of some D model and trying to link it. Instead of linking C as a whole, blender offers me to link A_proxy and B_proxy separately. Is it possible to treat C like it is a single object?

I'm not sure I use right terminology. But I want C to behave as an inseparable group maintaining the linking behavior(this group will change when I change A or B).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just group A and B?

Comment: @10Replies So, do you mean that I should group A and B in C and then link group in D? Is this the best way for managing deep object hierarchies?